# Does using scent to "note the direction" provoke an attack of opportunity?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, opportunity-attack, special-senses

Does a creature with the [scent ability](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Scent-Ex-) who uses their move action to note the direction of a scent provoke an Attack of Opportunity?

The [Scent](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Scent-Ex-) special ability allows that:

> When a creature detects a scent, the exact location of the source is not revealed—only its presence somewhere within range. The creature can take a move action to note the direction of the scent. When the creature is within 5 feet of the source, it pinpoints the source’s location.

Scent's description doesn't say one way or the other, and I can't find a general rule like "move actions generally do [not] provoke unless they say otherwise". The [description of AoOs](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Attacks-of-Opportunity) says:

> Some actions, when performed in a threatened square, provoke attacks of opportunity as you divert your attention from the battle. Table: Actions in Combat notes many of the actions that provoke attacks of opportunity.

The [table](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/Combat/#Table-Actions-in-Combat) is silent on scent. My next thought was to check [Perception](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/perception/)'s active use, but it's mum on AoOs, too (simply "Intentionally searching for stimulus is a move action.").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No.**

Scent is an [Extraordinary Ability](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/special-abilities/#TOC-Extraordinary-Abilities-Ex-). Using Extraordinary Abilities does not provoke attacks of opportunity.

Comment: ... of course, it _would_ be in the one place I didn't look; thanks!